# Could someone help me understand VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties?

Tags: memory-management, vulkan

I'm trying to figure it out, but I'm getting a little stuck.

The way the types and heaps are related is simple, if a bit strange. (why not just give `VkMemoryHeap` a `VkMemoryType` member?)

I think I understand what all the `VkMemoryPropertyFlags` mean, they seem fairly straightforward.

But what's with the `VkMemoryHeap.flags` member? It apparently only has one non-zero valid value, `VkMemoryHeapFlagBits.VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT`, and though that wouldn't be too odd on it's own, but there's also a `VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits.VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` that could be present on the memory type of the heap.

What does the `VkMemoryHeap.flags` member mean and how does it relate to the `VkMemoryType.flags` member?

Comment: I had the exact same question after reading that section, and hooray! It's already been asked and answered!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Vulkan recognizes two distinct concepts when it comes to memory. There are the actual physical pieces of RAM that the device can talk to. Then there are *ways* to allocate memory from one of those pools of RAM.

A heap represents a specific piece of RAM. `VkMemoryHeap` is the object that describes one of the available heaps of RAM that the device can talk to. There really aren't that many things that define a particular heap. Just two: the number of bytes of that RAMs storage and the storage's location relative to the Vulkan device (local vs. non-local).

A memory type is a particular *means* of allocating memory from a specific heap. `VkMemoryType` is the object that describes a particular way of allocating memory. And there are a lot more descriptive flags for how you can allocate memory from a heap.

For a more concrete example, consider a standard PC setup with a discrete GPU. The device has its own local RAM, but the discrete GPU can also access CPU memory. So a Vulkan device will have two heaps: one of them will be local, the other non-local.

However, there will usually be more than two memory *types*. You usually have one memory type that represents local memory, which does not have the `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT` set. That means you can't map the memory; you can only access it via transfer operations from some other memory type (or from rendering operations or whatever).

But you will often have two memory types that both use the same non-local heap. They will both be `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT`, thus allowing mapping. However, one of them will likely have the `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT` flag set, while the other will be `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT`. This allows you to choose whether you want cached CPU access (thus requiring an explicit flush of ranges of modified memory) or uncached CPU access.

But while they are two separate memory types, they both allocate from the same *heap*. Which is why `VkMemoryType` has an index that refers to the heap who's memory it is allocating from.

---

> Only thing I'm not getting is how the two `DEVICE_LOCAL` flags interact.

Did you look at the specification? It's not exactly hiding how this works:

> if `propertyFlags` has the `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` bit set, memory allocated with this type is the most efficient for device access. This property will only be set for memory types belonging to heaps with the `VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` set.

> Is it saying that if the memory is local then all types corresponding to that memory are local, or that they can be local?

You seem to be trying to impose the wrong meaning to these things. Just look at what the specification says and take it at face value.

`PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL` denotes a memory type which will achieve the best device access performance. The only connection between this and `MEMORY_DEVICE_LOCAL` is that memory types with `PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL` will only be associated with memory heaps that use `MEMORY_DEVICE_LOCAL`.

That's the only relevant meaning here.

If you want an example of when a memory heap would be device local, yet have memory types that aren't, consider a GPU that has no memory of its own. There's only one heap, which is therefore `MEMORY_DEVICE_LOCAL`.

However, allocating memory from that pool in a way that makes it host-visible may decrease the performance of device access to that memory. Therefore, [for such hardware](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=133), the host-visible memory types for the same heap will not use `PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL`.

Then again, [other hardware](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=239) doesn't lose performance from making memory host-visible. So they only have one memory type, which has all of the available properties. For Intel, their on-chip GPUs apparently have access to some level of the CPU's caches.

Comment: Quick follow up, would it be correct to say that if the heap does not have the `VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` flag set, then no memory types associated with it can have the `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` flag set? Only thing I'm not getting is how the two `DEVICE_LOCAL` flags interact.

Comment: @AlphaModder: Updated.

Comment: Whoops, somehow missed that. Is it saying that if the memory is local then all types corresponding to that memory are local, or that they _can_ be local?